# I don't have a job. Can I understate/underquote my last company's ctc to get more interview calls?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, india

I lost my job because of some cost cutting measures in my last company in Bangalore. As my last company was an MNC, my CTC (cost to company) was slightly on the higher side (have over 10yrs of IT Exp in Software Development).

I have posted my resume in job portals like Naukri.com and monsterindia.com and I am getting calls from IT Service consultancies for job openings for their clients. They as a routine enquire about my current CTC, total Yrs and relevent yrs of experience.

But I find that for a major of the job openings in Indian companies, the CTC range is 10 to 20% less than my current CTC. Because of this I am not getting enough interview calls (my profile is not getting shortlisted for interview. On few occasions, the consultants have told me that the budget for this position is xxx, would you still be interested, for which I promptly agree).

Though I tell them that I am OK with the company standards (and ready to take a CTC cut) as I am currently not working, this does not seem to help the cause.

Wanted to know if it was a good idea to understate/underquote my last companies CTC by say 10-15% lesser when they call me up for my availability for a job position so that I can at-least get a change to attend interview process which I would otherwise not be getting at all?

Comment: A common problem in India! I think I'd write an answer later today :)   How much is your salary after all those tax and other cuttings in % of the CTC?

Comment: CTC is 16.9 Lakhs. After income taxes, Provident Fund deductions, Insurance premium, anniversary bonus deduction etc, the monthly credit to my bank account was about 85K. Bonus is also part of this CTC and given on completion of anniversary. In terms of % the per month take-home is 60% of CTC. If you consider the Bonus component as well and split it across 12 months, monthly takehome is 75% of CTC.

Comment: Do you have proof that  you are not getting enough interview calls *because of the CTC*, or are you just *assuming*? If you don't know for sure understating won't help you.

Comment: India is amazing. How would I even get to *know* my CTC? If the company provides me with a parking space and desk, why would *I* care how much *they* paid for it? That's *their* freaking problem.

Comment: You're asking if it's okay to lie on your CV?

Comment: @JanDoggen I believe so as many have told that their budget for the current opening is only xyz amount which is below what your current CTC is. Is it OK with you?. Though I said that I was OK, none of them got back to me.

Comment: Do you have to give your CTC in the resume/application? Is leaving it off an option? Lying is not a good option in any case.

Comment: No. You don't specify the CTC in the resume. But generally they call you to confirm details like your current CTC, work experience, current location etc before processing your resume/profile.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this CTC concept but when they ask you what the figure is, can't you say "I'm okay with this or that amount" ? Do they drill you for your past CTCs ?If they do, can't you tell them you are not really aware of the figure and you just know your take home pay and make it in-line with what you expect from this employer at the present market rates.

Comment: @MelBurslan Nope. I generally start that way saying that I am Ok with what ever amount you are offering. But all of them insist on knowing your current CTC as the recruiter needs to know it. Generally the offer document or the salary increment document after every anniversary will specify the CTC clearly. So you cannot claim being ignorant of your CTC either.

Comment: Dont lie. If they insist on knowing, you can either politely insist on not saying the number ("I'd prefer to apply without divulging"), or you have to give it to them.

Comment: In the US at least, every employer asks what your salary was in your last/current position, but you are in no way obligated to tell them. If you are sufficiently valuable to the employer, it's in your interest to say what you are looking to make, as opposed to what you made in the past. Many in the US believe they are somehow required to reveal salary history.

Answer (score 3):

I believe lying to recruiter or the HR is a bad idea. Even if your assumption is correct that you are not getting interview calls because of your old CTC being on the higher side, consider the following scenario:

You lie to the recruiter and get an interview and clear it. Now before offering you anything, the HR would need to go through proofs of your old compensation packages and salary slips. You would be caught and they may refuse to offer anything. It would be worse if they ask for the documents, post-joining.

I would suggest opening up relocation options and trying for opportunities in other cities like Pune or Hyderbad. IT salaries in Banglore are considered to be on the higher side, compared to these cities.

Comment: Of course I will be telling them my correct CTC during the HR round and also tell them that I am ok will a lower CTC (if the company is offering a lower amount). My question here is that will they accept the earlier lie of understating my CTC and the justification for the same?

Comment: Any lie will raise questions about how much they can trust you, even if they understand your intent. Nobody likes false advertising.

Comment: Agree with @keshlam. They are bound to find out the lie at one stage or the other and at any stage it is bound to raise suspicisons about your career claims.

Answer (score -1):

> Wanted to know if it was a good idea to understate/underquote my last
>   companies CTC by say 10-15% lesser when they call me up for my
>   availability for a job position

Firstly, the entire concept of bloated CTC(Cost-to-company) salaries are a big problem in India. That is especially rampant for people trying to come into startups from huge companies, as startups freak out at those huge numbers. But, the truth is that the takeaway amount is not as big as they assume.

So, **YES you can lie in the resume**, and then cover it up somehow later by explaining yourself. And as you are okay with an amount somewhat lesser than the actual, companies would be okay with it. But, how much you want to project is completely up to you, as that should be a very calculated risk.

So, don't project very less, lest you end up dissatisfied with the money.